# RewriteCond scope in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect non-existing files with versioned filename to the current version. There are two target files depending on a pattern in the requested filename.

For example the current file is *setup-win-3-1-0.exe*
A request for *setup-win-2-7-1.exe* (non existent) would redirect to the previous one. (And setup-mac-2-7-1.dmg would go to setup-mac-3-1-0.dmg)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^setup-win-[^.]+\.exe$ setup-win-%{ENV:DOWNLWIN}.exe [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^setup-mac-[^.]+\.dmg$ setup-mac-%{ENV:DOWNLMAC}.dmg [L,R=301,NC]
```

(The ENV:DOWNL is set before, omited for clarity)

I've been searching the web and I find some contradictions, I've seen that RewriteCond applies only to the next RewriteRule and in other places that it applies until it fins a RweriteRule with Last flag.

- Would that RewriteCond apply to both lines?
- If so, when does stop that RewriteCond? (if I have more Rules following, would they still be in the scope of the Cond?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would that RewriteCond apply to both lines?

Answer is **No**. `RewriteCond` is only applicable to the nearest `RewriteRule`. It is never applied to more than one rules defined using `RewriteRule` directive.

**Alternative Approach:** If you don't to want `RewriteCond` over and over again before all the rules then have a separate **skip-all* rule using opposite of the `RewriteCond`. Consider below example:

```
RewriteEngine 

# skip all the rules *below* of comdition is met
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^setup-win-[^.]+\.exe$ setup-win-%{ENV:DOWNLWIN}.exe [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^setup-mac-[^.]+\.dmg$ setup-mac-%{ENV:DOWNLMAC}.dmg [L,R=301,NC]
```